# Changing a cell value in a xlsl sheet while keeping the format nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, xlsx

Title is what I'm trying to achieve. Basically I want to edit a existing excel sheet that is formatted with fonts/styles etc and keep those fonts/styles intact while changing a particular cells value.

I've tried using the xlsx npm module, I've been able to change the cell to the value I want and save the file, but when doing so all the style is lost.

I was wondering if you guys could give me any directions on what to try now.

I only want to use nodejs for this project.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

In [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) it says: *The raw data is the only thing guaranteed to be saved. Formulae, formatting, and other niceties may not be serialized (pending CSF standardization)* under **writing options** section.